# How to get piece of string before first non-numeric character in PHP

Tags: php

I have strings with the following pattern: `12345ABCDE6789` where each group of numbers and letters are a variable length. There will only ever be numbers and letters, no special characters.

I need a way to get the numbers up until the first letter, so that the example above would return `12345`.

My thought was I could find the string position of the first letter and then trim the string to that position. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to get that index without knowing what the character is. Other solutions I've found have had the knowledge that the first letter would be an "A" where mine could be any letter.

Is there a concise way to do this?

I do not have much experience with regex, but maybe something there would be a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Why ask and answer your own (very trivial) question?

Comment: I didn't answer my own question?

Comment: I have mistaken the *edited by* with *asked by*. I am sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$re = '/^[0-9]+/m';
$str = '12345ABCDE6789';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]); // 12345
```

https://regexr.com/4mcfr

Answer (score 3):

So long as the number will be <= 2147483647 for 32 bit systems and <= 9223372036854775807 for 64 bit, then the simplest is to cast to an integer and it will truncate letters (anything that will not return a valid integer):

```
echo (int)"12345ABCDE6789";
```

Returns `12345`